# NHibernate code genaration tool for asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Any idea of any tool I can use to generate asp.net (c#) scripts  for NHibernate.

I was told some come with unitTest Scripts as well. I just need a good template to start a project using NHibernate with C# web application.

This a new territory for me

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

[LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com) comes with a code generator for Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I always used [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) and grab one of the NHibernate templates from that.

Answer (score 0):

[NhGen from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nhgen/) doesn't generate page templates, but it can read a database schema and generate all the required classes, mappings, NHibernate session wrappers and it does include some unit tests. The app also come with the assembies from NHibernate.Burrows which wraps up the transactions. That might help.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need

http://tekpub.com/production/nhibernate

Money well spent!

Comment: Well, the question was not very clear so I thought some guidance might be useful.